# is there a way to hide or encode url path?

Tags: php, url, odbc, wampserver

i'm using php $_GET to get data from url path but i want it to hide or encode the url path after finish using it.

example : http://10.1.6.8/?no=CN%20-%20005 and after it finish running it will turn url into http://10.1.6.8/QAIOFANGQNIOGND or http://10.1.6.8/
or something that didn't point directly to url path. is that possible?

EDIT 1
i can't use $_POST because i have to make url into QR Code and after scanning it i want the url path to hide or decode
EDIT 2 I manage to change url path name by using .htaccess but $_GET value still appear

Comment: Answers in this may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751124/url-parameters-value-encryption-decryption?lq=1

Comment: Why do you need to "hide" it? If this is about security, then simply obscuring the ID is not a secure solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking to make a [POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) instead, which would hide all parameters in the URL. You can do this with forms by adding `method="POST"` instead of `"GET"`.

Unfortunately, your question doesn't really specify your use case.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i can't use $_POST cause i have to turn the url into qr code