# PHP encrypt and decrypt string to be url friendly

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I am trying to figure out a way to encrypt a user id number. My idea is to encrypt the id ( between 1 and 5 characters ) in combination with some letters ( like _wordtouse ). The only two requirements are

1. The crypted version can only contain a maximum of 15 characters
2. I need to be able to decrypt the string on a different page

The reason for all of this is that i am trying to "hide" user id numbers when someone enters a users profile. So i am trying to find a way to deliver an encrypted version of the user id through the url as a get parameter.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189841/1325575 explains this in-depth.

However, the short version, which requires no 3rd party installs:

1. Use [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) for encryption
2. Use  [openssl_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) for decryption

I'm confident that with those 3 links you're gonna find what you're after.

Comment: If the question has been answered elsewhere you should delete your answer and flag it as a duplicate

Comment: @Nino Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest just using the [hashids library](http://hashids.org/php/) which is pretty popular and what many url shortening services use. While it isn't really "encryption", it is likely good enough to hide a user's id number in a url. Example:

```
$userID = 1234;
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('some random secret string');

//encode the user id
$encodedID = $hashids->encode($user_id);

//on the other page, decode the user id
$decodedID = $hashids->decode($encodedID);
```

Comment: Seems cool, a sample would be nice tho.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac I did include an example in the answer. There is also quite a lot more information on their own website which I linked to.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant an example of the output.

Comment: I used [hashids library](https://github.com/vinkla/hashids) in 2 large projects, it's an amazing library!

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered here I believe: [Encrypt/Encoding an ID in URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940348/encrypt-encoding-an-id-in-url-string)

But I would like to add that instead of using mcrypt ([the project is abandoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mcrypt)) you should use: Libsodium, or defuse/php-encryption or OpenSSL

Comment: If the question has been answered elsewhere you should delete your answer and flag it as a duplicate

Comment: @Machavity, the previous answer advices to use mcrypt which is abandoned, that is why I added which alternatives to use IMO